# Java MergeSort: Compare and Swap Counters

Tags: java, mergesort

I have the following MergeSort class and I have to implement compare and swap counters. Can someone please confirm if my compare and swap counters are in the right locations?

As you'll see, I have two class properties for the swap and compare counters. Where I'm not exactly positive is where A) I initialize the swapCount and compareCount (in runSort method or mergeSort method?) and B) where exactly swapCount++ in the merge method should be placed. I'm pretty sure compareCount++ is in the right place though.

Here's the code. Thanks in advance to all who reply!

```
public class MyMergeSort {

    private int swapCount;
    private int compareCount;

    public void runSort() {
        //this.compareCount = 0;
        //this.swapCount = 0;

        mergeSort(this.sortItems,0,sortItems.length);
    }

    public void mergeSort(String[] data, int first, int n) {

        int n1; // Size of the first half of the array
        int n2; // Size of the second half of the array
        this.compareCount = 0;
        this.swapCount = 0;

        if (n > 1) {
            // Compute sizes of the two halves
            n1 = n / 2;
            n2 = n - n1;

            mergeSort(data, first, n1);      // Sort data[first] through data[first+n1-1]
            mergeSort(data, first + n1, n2); // Sort data[first+n1] to the end

            // Merge the two sorted halves.
            merge(data, first, n1, n2);
        }

    }

    private void merge(String[] data, int first, int n1, int n2) {

        String[] temp = new String[n1+n2]; // Allocate the temporary array
        int copied  = 0; // Number of elements copied from data to temp
        int copied1 = 0; // Number copied from the first half of data
        int copied2 = 0; // Number copied from the second half of data
        int i;           // Array index to copy from temp back into data

        // Merge elements, copying from two halves of data to the temporary array.
        while ((copied1 < n1) && (copied2 < n2)) {

            compareCount++;

            if (data[first + copied1].compareTo(data[first + n1 + copied2]) < 0) {
                temp[copied++] = data[first + (copied1++)];

                //swapCount++;

            }
            else {
                temp[copied++] = data[first + n1 + (copied2++)];

                swapCount++;
            }
        }

        // Copy any remaining entries in the left and right subarrays.
        while (copied1 < n1)
            temp[copied++] = data[first + (copied1++)];
        while (copied2 < n2)
            temp[copied++] = data[first + n1 + (copied2++)];

        // Copy from temp back to the data array.
        for (i = 0; i < n1+n2; i++)
            data[first + i] = temp[i];
    }

}
```

** Update 11/28/2017 ** Good news. I think I finally found just what I was looking for:

http://www.cs.carleton.edu/faculty/adalal/teaching/f04/117/notes/nov08/Sort.java

Big thanks to the author of that code!

Comment: You should initialise your counts in `runSort`. If you initialise them in `mergeSort` you'll overwrite them on every recursive call.

Comment: Thanks teppic. And think I found something that points me even further in the right direction from what appears to be a credible source: 

http://www.cs.carleton.edu/faculty/adalal/teaching/f04/117/notes/nov08/Sort.java

Answer (score 0):

To implement proper counting, you need to increment the count value every time the thing you are counting occurs.  For example:

```
if (n > 2) {
   a = b;
   swapCount++;
}
compareCount++; // because the condition of the if statement
```

This means you may need to structure your methods such that `swapCount` and `compareCount` are accessible, and rework your logic such that short-circuiting doesn't diverge from the actual count.  For example, you could not write

```
if ((a > 5) && (b > 5)) {
  ...
}
```

and get an easy way of updating the `compareCount` because you'd need to add in logic to see if one compare was done, or two.  To do that, you'd add at least an additional compare

```
if (a > 5) {
   compareCount++;
} else {
   compareCount += 2;
}
```

Instead it would be much better to simply write your compound comparison in a different way

```
if (a > 5) {
   if (b > 5) {
   }
   compareCount++;
}
compareCount++;
```

Which reads more poorly in the "if statement" but is cleaner in determining the conditions for incrementing `compareCount`.

Comment: Thanks Edwin, good info. And wanted to share some sample code I just found online that coupled with your post, should be just what I need to really understand this sort algorithm: 

http://www.cs.carleton.edu/faculty/adalal/teaching/f04/117/notes/nov08/Sort.java

Comment: Yes, but beware.  That code has quite a few of the compares not being done.  For example, in the if loops, a compare is done for each iteration of the if loop, if the condition portion of the if loop contains a compare operation.